# Is it possible to get a list of all active auctions on ENS?

Tags: testnets, ens, auctions

On testnet, there is currently a registrar running for first-in-first-served (FIFS) `.test` domains, which can be directly claimed for 30 days, and the auction registrar for `.eth` domains, which require a 7-day public auction to claim a domain.

Is it possible to get a list of all active auctions on `.eth` domains from the ENS?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by subscribing to the [AuctionStarted](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/HashRegistrarSimplified.sol#L113) event. Set a filter to iterate over all blocks in the past week for efficiency:

```
ethRegistrar.AuctionStarted(
    {},
    {fromBlock: web3.eth.getBlockNumber('latest') - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) / 14, toBlock: 'latest'},
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result.args.hash + " expires " + result.args.auctionExpiryDate);
    });
```

Returned values are the sha3 hashes of the names under auction, so you'll need a dictionary of preimages if you want to figure out what they are in plaintext.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on monitoring historical events in this manner? I have only ever seen web3.eth.filter.. Also, your link points to 'master' rather than a specific commit. Thanks

Comment: This is just event filtering [as described in the web3 docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events).

Answer (score 3):

See here at etherscan https://etherscan.io/ens?filter=auctionskn

use "FILTER BY" to show other infos